# For a gradient system $\dot{x}=-\nabla V(x)$, $V$ is $C^2$, prove the eigenvalues of the derivative of the vector field at every fixed point are real

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I want to show that for a gradient system $\dot{x}=-\nabla V(x)$, where $V$ is $C^2$, the eigenvalues of the derivative of the vector field at every fixed point are real.

I know that if $x_0$ is a fixed point then $\nabla V(x_0)=0$, but have no idea where to go from this.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of the vector field is the Hessean of the potential. For a $C^2$ function that is a symmetric matrix, now apply the spectral theory of symmetric or self-adjoint matrices.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Does this mean that being at a fixed point is irrelevant, or has that implicitly been used somewhere?

Comment: Indeed. But these eigenvalues are only relevant at stationary points, where displacement vectors are transported to the same tangent space at the same point. Thus it makes little sense to compute them elsewhere.